# Mongodb find query array starts with element

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have collection where document like:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "path" : [ 3, 1 ], "name" : "A" }
{ "_id" : 2, "path" : [ 3, 1, 1 ], "name" : "B" }
{ "_id" : 3, "path" : [ 3, 1, 1, 1 ], "name" : "C" }
{ "_id" : 4, "path" : [ 3, 1, 2 ], "name" : "D" }
{ "_id" : 5, "path" : [ 3, 1, 2, 1 ], "name" : "E" }
{ "_id" : 6, "path" : [ 3, 1, 3 ], "name" : "F" }
{ "_id" : 7, "path" : [ 3, 2 ], "name" : "G" }
{ "_id" : 8, "path" : [ 3, 2,1 ], "name" : "H" }
```

Now I’m trying to query which all path starts with  3,1:

```
db.exp3.find({"path": {"$elemMatch": {"0": 3}}});
```

not working .

Any hints?

Comment: I found one solution :db.exp3.find({$where : "this.path[0]==3 && this.path[1] == 1"}); Is there any other approch .

Comment: Please read [the warning on this page](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) about using `$where`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can query it as follows :

```
db.myObject.find({"path.0" : 3, "path.1" : 1})
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively if you can store path as a string, then you can index it and a starts with query can you use an anchored query to make it use the index.
e.g.

```
db.so.insert({ "_id" : 1, "path" : "3/1", "name" : "A" })
db.so.insert({ "_id" : 2, "path" : "3/1/1", "name" : "B" })
....
db.so.ensureIndex({path:1})
db.so.find({path:/^3\/1/})
```